# Difference between the javascript/jQuery events "focus" and "focusin"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between these two events: `focus` and `focusin`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [`focusin`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event, in that it supports detecting the `focus` event on parent elements (in other words, **it supports event bubbling**).

This event will likely be used together with the `focusout` event.

Answer (score 7):

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Answer (score 4):

According to the [jQuery `focusin` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/):

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside
>   of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it
>   supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words,
>   it supports event bubbling).

Answer (score 1):

The focusin  events bubble, the focus  events doesn't. That means that you can use the focusin on the parent element of a form field.