# Difference between focusin/focusout and focus/blur, with example

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me the difference between `blur` and `focusout`, `focus` and `focusin` with a simple example?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `focusin` and `focusout` events bubble, the `focus` and `blur` events doesn't. That means that you can use the `focusin` and `focusout` on the parent element of a form field.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pAp4E/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.parent')
    .focusin(function(){log('div focusin');})
    .focusout(function(){log('div focusout');})
    .focus(function(){log('div focus');})
    .blur(function(){log('div blur');});
$('input')
    .focusin(function(){log('input focusin');})
    .focusout(function(){log('input focusout');})
    .focus(function(){log('input focus');})
    .blur(function(){log('input blur');});

function log(str){
  $('.log').append($('<div/>').text(str));
}
```

When you run it, you see that only the input gets all the events, the parent only gets the `focusin` and `focusout` events.

Comment: August 2015 - Firefox still does not support focusin/focusout (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin). Man they did drop the ball ...

Comment: @ArnaudLeyder: Yes, it's still not implemented in Firefox, but jQuery emulates it.

Comment: yeah you are right. Because I do not use jQuery for this project I used a polyfill: https://gist.github.com/nuxodin/9250e56a3ce6c0446efa

Answer (score 11):

The focus and blur events keep track of the elements the user focuses on.

1. focus

   Fires when a focusable element gains the focus
2. blur

   Fires when a focusable element loses the focus
3. focusin and focusout

   Fire at the same time as focus and blur, but bubble.

for example [check this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/focus-blur)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between focus and focusin:

focus & blur - doesn't bubble, can't be delegated,
focusin & focusout   -  bubbles to the parent element, can be delegated.