# blur vs focusout -- any real differences?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any difference between JS events **blur** vs **focusout**?

I have two textboxes: `password` and `confirm_password`.

I want to check password match when user tabs out of the confirm pwd textbox, for example.

In this case which event should I use or does it matter?

Answer (score 296, accepted):

The documentation for [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) says (*emphasis* mine):

> The `focusout` event is sent to an element when it, *or any element
>   inside of it*, loses focus. This is distinct from the `blur` event in
>   that *it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements* (in
>   other words, it supports event bubbling).

The same distinction exists between the [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) and [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus) events.

Comment: It supports detecting the loss of focus from **child** elements, not from parent elements. If the documentation used to say **parent**, it was wrong. Now it says **descendant elements**.

Comment: I probably read both of these answers and the documentation like 7 times before I understood it—`focusout` supports loss of focus on descendant elements and event bubbling, not `blur`.  Confusing wording there.  Put more simply: `blur` supports losing focus on only the element in question; `focusout` supports losing focus on the element in question and any children.

Comment: @intcreator thank you, I only understood after your explanation.

Comment: As much as i tested `focusout` seems to be much better than `blur`!

Comment: `blur` didnt catch tabbing out of an element `focusout` did

Comment: I have found simple answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example

Answer (score 138):

As stated in the **[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)**

> The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. **This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).**