# How to submit an Ajax form on focusout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following form, submitted by AJAX:

HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formEditUsername" action="<?php echo URL; ?>account/editusername_action" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="Add username" value="User ">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

AJAX

```
$("#formEditUsername").submit(function(event){
        //disable default click operation
        event.preventDefault();

        var action_url = $(this).attr("action");
       $(".help-block.username").hide().html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin'></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Processing...").fadeIn('slow');
       console.log(action_url);
       var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        //console.log(postData);

        $.post(action_url,postData,function(data){

            console.log(data);
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(".help-block.username").html("Saving...");

            if(obj.status == "error")
            {
            $(".help-block.username").css({color: '#990033'});
            $(".help-block.username").html(obj.message).fadeIn('slow');

            };

            if(obj.status == "success")
            {
                $(".help-block.username").css({color: '#00b25a'});
                $(".help-block.username").html(obj.message).fadeIn('slow');
                $(".namebox").html(obj.username);
            }
        });

    });
```

I want to add a feature so that the form submits with focusout(), after the input (#user_name) loses focus. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#user_name').on('focusout', function() {
    $("#formEditUsername").trigger('submit');
});
```

Read this : http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#user_name').on('blur', function() {
    $("#formEditUsername").trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, why would I use blur rather than focusout as per Rajaprabhu's answer?

Comment: @alias51 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973532/blur-vs-focusout-any-real-differences

Comment: You have an input element, and the correct event for that element is the blur event, while the focusout event is intended to be used where you need bubbling magic added by jQuery.

Comment: `$("#formEditUsername").trigger('submit');` will this submit the FORM? Because OP is preventing default behaviour in jquery submit handler so triggering this event won't submit FORM, right?!

Comment: @A.Wolff - The title being "How to submit an Ajax form" I assumed the point was to trigger the submit handler, and as such submit the form with ajax, as it would be a PITA if the page reloaded on every blur event ?

Comment: @A.Wolff - no problem, completely valid question, and I'm just assuming, the only one who has the answer is the OP ?

Comment: Correct, the title says it all. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

To submit form, use:

```
$('#user_name').on('focusout', function() {
    $("#formEditUsername").get(0).submit(); // this fires JS native event, not jquery handler
});
```