# Hide placeholder test onfocus on firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I use HTML5 placeholder attribute to label form elements.

I wish to hide the placeholder onfocus event, But in firefox it dissappears only when user starts to type.

It goes well with on all other web browsers when i use the following style

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

but not on latest version of firefox.

How to hide placeholder onfocus on firefox browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having jQuery option too. Try this:

```
var placeholderValue = "";
$('input').focus(function () {
  placeholderValue = $(this).attr('placeholder'); // save the value
  $(this).attr('placeholder', ''); // remove the value for that
}
$('input').blur(function () {
  $(this).attr('placeholder', placeholderValue); // update the value! :)
}
```

And do the counter for this, when there is a blur event, give it back its value!

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/nHYhK/1/

I have tested in my Firefox :-) And it works perfect!

Comment: This does work, but when you focus and outfocus, the value is lost forever. That's why i am trying it with css

Comment: @JaganK there you go :) i have updated the fiddle and added code to store the value too :)

Comment: I am thinking of using focusout function, do you think blur is better?

Comment: I have no perfect answer for that, yet you can get an answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973532/blur-vs-focusout-any-real-differences :) GOod luck!

Answer (score 0):

moz for use mozilla

> Blockquote

`input:-moz-placeholder {
    color:transparent;
}`