# Focusout function negates submit on click

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I have an animating search bar that is meant to hide when the user clicks outside of it. This however causes a direct click on the submit button next to it to be ignored. How can I go around this?

HTML,

```
    <form role="search" id="searchform" method="get" action="/">
      <i class="icon icon-search"></i>
      <a id="search-toggle" href="#"></a>
      <input type="submit" value="">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="s" value="">
    </form>
```

CSS (SCSS),

```
form {
            margin: 0;
            input {
                float: right;
            }
            input[type="text"] {
                height: 3rem;
                margin: 5px 0 0 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 0;
                @include transition(all, .2s, ease-in-out);
                &.active {
                    width: 80%;
                    padding: .5rem 1rem;
                }
            }
            input[type="submit"] {
                width: 4rem;
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        }
    a, i {
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 4rem;
        width: 4rem;
        height: 4rem;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    i {
        pointer-events: none;
        color: $light-grey;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        z-index: 30;
        padding: 3px 0 0 0;
        @include transition(color, .2s, ease);
    }
```

JS,

```
  $('#search').focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
```

Also tried using blur() instead of focusout(), same result.

Edit: Added some additional code. I'm having an icon and invisible link button overlaying the submit button to prevent it from submitting at once - I want to animate and display the search box first. After that box is revealed and the user types in something, this is when I run into trouble reaching the submit event. Now it requires two clicks, one to first close the box, then a second to trigger the button.

Comment: Can you post the code for the search bar? What type of element it is?

Comment: This is an extremely broad description. Please show some code that can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here, and maybe you can clarify your reasoning.

Is there are reason you're toggling the class `active` instead of using the `:focus` pseudo class for styling? This still allows keyboard usage, and you could bind something to that toggle link like this:

```
$('#search-toggle').click(function(){
    $('#search').focus();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

If you don't want it to shrink down, you could apply the style when anything in that form is focused via css (note that I use a recommend a search input type instead of text):

```
form *:focus ~ input[type="search"] {
     width: 80%;
     padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: The reason is I wanted to add an animation as well for the focus event (highlight color). But I'll just skip that and go with this, it works and its clean. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to add CSS transitions here just as you would any other CSS styling. I'd give it a try.

Comment: Yes. Now I just need to figure out how to toggle focus of another element (via the link button).

Comment: Unsure what you mean. You mean when you click the #search-toggle link, you want to apply focus to something other than the #search item, or what?

Comment: I have a similar feature done in a different manner here: http://alistafart.com/. Take a look at my source and see if that's the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks. AlistAfart? ;)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but it happens that I had the same issue and resolved it other way, so maybe the following code could be handy to someone else:

```
$('#text_input_id').blur(function(event){

    //event.relatedTarget gets the object that triggered the blur event(or "focus
    // out" event), in this case if it is a submit input, ignore the blur event.
    if($(event.relatedTarget).prop('type') === 'submit'){
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
    else {
        //Do whatever you want when focusing out. For instance:
        $('#search').css('display', 'none');
    }

});
```

### **¿Why this works?**

The `focusout` or `blur` events (see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973560/2780308)) do prevent the submit button to work properly, because some how it overrides the `submit` event, which then causes the odd behavior of clicking twice to submit. The trick here is to use the `event.relatedTarget`, which gets the object that triggered the `blur` event. In this case, if it is any submit button `<input type="submit" value="Search">`), then call `event.preventDefault()` to workaround the issue.

Comment: Coming from the future; I could never imaging googling these keywords would get me the exact same issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the submit button from being pushed when the user hasn't entered anything in the search box, you can disable it by default, and then enable it once the user types something into the search input (this would allow you to not cover up the submit button with your anchor tag):

Submit button HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="" disabled>
```

jQuery to enable the submit button only after keyup event in the search box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") $(":submit").prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Comment: Ah, yes this is sort of what I added:

  $('#search').keydown(function() {
    $('#search-toggle').hide();
  });