# What is the difference between window.focus() and window.blur()?

Tags: javascript

I'm new learner of `JavaScript`...I couldn't find out the difference between `window.focus();` and `window.blur();`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="focus()">Click</button>
<script>
 function focus() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");
myWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</body>
```

---

When I am using them I cant find out any action on window by them....

Help me to find out the use of them ...:)

Comment: they are the opposite of each other ... blur removes focus (it's an analog to a camera!!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between focusin/focusout and focus/blur, with example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer...This code is very useful to know the actions by both of them..

```
 var focus = true;
 window.onblur = function() { focus = true; document.title="NEW MESSAGE";}
 window.onfocus = function() { focus = true; document.title="Talk"; }
 document.onblur = window.onblur;
 document.focus = window.focus;

 function msg(){
 window.open("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=luC_V_v_C8aAoAP-7ofwDA")
if(focus) {
    document.title="Talk";
} else {
    document.title="NEW MESSAGE";
}
}
msg();`
```

I got answer from the following link

> [refer following link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/check-if-window-is-focused/4398/8)

Answer (score 5):

They are basically opposite:

`window.focus` Assure that the new window **GETS** focus (send the new window to the front).

`window.blur` Assure that the new window does **NOT** get focus (send the new window to the background).

*Examples:*

-`window.focus()`:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100"); // Opens a new window
myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>"); // Some text in the new window
myWindow.focus(); // Assures that the new window gets focus
```

-`window.blur()`:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200, height=100"); // Opens a new window
myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>"); // Some text in the new window
myWindow.blur(); // Assures that the new window does NOT get focus
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use chrome console to run this code
1.`var myWindow = window.open("http://www.runoob.com","newwindow", "width=200,height=100");`
2.`myWindow.focus();`
3.`myWindow.blur();`
after run this three line code you can understand what's the difference between window.focus() and window.blur()