# How to minimise textarea when clicking out of if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code to maximise a text area when you click into it. How can I return it to it's original size when I click out of the textarea?

```
$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "300px" }, 500);
});
```

Comment: [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tmnasim/sXbaT/

Comment: You don't really need javascript for that: http://jsfiddle.net/4hwrd3y4/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/k3aztqof/1/

```js
$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "300px" }, 500);
}).focusout(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "100px" }, 500);
});
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I'll accept this as you've given the most complete answer. Thanks to you and everyone else who've provided answers.

Comment: It is important to mention, that `focusout` is not the "real pair" of `focus`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example (Off course, it does not matter in this particular case)

Answer (score 1):

The pair of the `focus` event is `blur` (https://api.jquery.com/blur/), so you will want to resize on blur:

```
$('textarea').blur(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "XXXpx" }, 500);
});
```

**EDIT:** But you may want to use a CSS-only solution:

```
textarea {
  height:200px;
}
textarea:focus {
  height:300px;
}
```

Further, you can also use some CSS animation technique to visually enhance the transition.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').onblur = function() {
  if(this.value === this.defaultValue) {
  this.style.height = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "focusout" JavaScript event.

```js
$('textarea').focus(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 500);
});

$('textarea').focusout(function() {
 $(this).animate({
    height: "100px"
  }, 500);
})
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do with [`blur`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjX56bylKTVAhVHhbwKHYwzCqsQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fblur%2F&usg=AFQjCNHkVKvgNRyXXHHLHCCu2U86wt-LLA) event and set height with `initial`

```js
$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "300px" }, 500);
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).animate({ height: "initial" }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>sss</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user jquery `focusin()` and `focusout()` methods to increase and decrease the size:

```
//increase size on focus in
$('textarea').focusin(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "300px" }, 500);
});

//decrease size on focus out    
$('textarea').focusout(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "initial" }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var org_height = $('textarea').height();

$('textarea').focus(function () {
    $(this).animate({ height: "500px" }, 500);
});

$('textarea').focusout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ height: org_height }, 500);
});

</script>
```