# html+css+js dropdown menu exit on click

Tags: javascript

I have few dropdown selections and I'm trying to implement an exit function on click anywhere on the document so the dropdown list will close up. At the moment it only close up if you click on itself or another selection.

```
const selection = document.querySelectorAll('.selection-selected');
const optionContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.options-container');

function toggleSelection() {
    const selectionToggle = this.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    for (i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
      selection[i].setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    }
    
    if (selectionToggle == "false") {
        this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");

    } 
}
selection.forEach(serviceItem => serviceItem.addEventListener("click", toggleSelection));

   
//Channel Selection
const channelSelection = document.querySelector('.channel');
const optionList = document.querySelectorAll('.channel-option');

optionList.forEach( o => {
  o.addEventListener("click", () => {
    channelSelection.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
    channelSelection.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    channelSelection.style.color = "#000";
    
  })
})

for (i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
  if(selection[i].ariaExpanded == "true") {
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      selection[i].setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    })
  }
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work so I'm looking someone who can advice me a solution for this. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please post enough of your (relevant, representative) "*[mcve]*" code, including HTML and CSS, to reproduce and demonstrate your problem. That way we can provide answers better tailored to your specific situation that will help you - and other future visitors - to learn.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `blur` or `focusout`, so when you tab out or click anywhere in the doc, `blur` or `focusout` event will trigger for that element and then you can fire the event, and close the dropdown.

Here are some example. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858979/difference-between-focusin-focusout-and-focus-blur-with-example)