# What is the difference between focusin/focusout vs focus/blur in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was handling some events using the following code with [jQuery 1.7.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js):

```
$().on('focus blur', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

And I have noticed that `event.type` for both events, prints out: `focusin` and `focusout`.

What is difference between `focusin/focusout` vs `focus/blur`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Short answer: `focusin`    bubbles, `focus` does not.**
         **`focusout`  bubbles, `blur`   does not.**
Read the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/):

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

Comment: To reduce confusion: "in that **it** supports detecting the focus event on parent elements" refers to the **focusin** event.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/):

> The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside
>   of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it
>   supports detecting the focus event on parent elements **(in other words,
>   it supports event bubbling)**.

And yes, you can find the same answer also here: [Difference between the javascript/jQuery events "focus" and "focusin"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311143/difference-between-the-javascript-jquery-events-focus-and-focusin)

Answer (score 2):

The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus. This is distinct from the focus event in that it supports detecting the focus event on parent elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/)