# Why event.bubbles is false for "focusin" and "focusout"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focusin

Couple of minutes ago, I answered the question:
 [What is the difference between focusin/focusout vs focus/blur in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10584042/601179)

The answer was:

**Short answer: `focusin`    bubbles, `focus` does not.**
         **`focusout`  bubbles, `blur`   does not.**

I tested it, it's true, but I encountered a weird thing while trying to set up a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/95u6a/):

```
$('#test').on('focusin focusout focus blur change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + 'event bubles? : ' + e.bubbles);
});​
```

`focusin` and `focusout` give me `e.bubbles == false`

Is it a bug of jQuery or am I missing the obvious here?

Comment: False/false in Chrome 18 (in case you want some browser notes...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Sounds like a bug in jQuery.</s> Did you test this on a browser that supports `focusin` and `focusout` natively? (E.g., IE?) Because if not, you're testing the flag for jQuery's emulated support.

I've crossed out the "Sounds like a bug" bit above because jQuery doesn't claim to normalize the `bubbles` property in the documentation. So since it doesn't guarantee it, it doesn't have to support it on emulated events. (Note that if I run your demo on IE7, I get `undefined` because IE7 doesn't support the DOM3 Events `bubbles` property.) Still an *issue*, but perhaps not a *bug*. :-)

---

**Update**:

Response on [the jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11763):

> The documentation doesn't claim to normalize the event.bubbles property. You can look for it in event.originalEvent but that will be whatever the platform provided, unnormalized.

So my guess above was correct. It's not a *bug*, because they don't claim to normalize that. :-)